# How to handle very large 3D data in Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I have a large input feature as 3D array of size `500x500x500` and `10000` of such samples. And the label of size `500x500x500x500`. 
I created a model with input shape of `500x500x500` using only one `Conv3D` layer at input and `Dense` layer at output (I have my own reason for dense layer at output) , the output shape of the network is `500x500x500x500`.

Below is the bare minimum model which I used:

```
ip = Input(shape=(500,500,500,1))  
x = Conv3D(100,3,activation="relu",padding='same')(ip)
x = Dense(500,activation="softmax")(x)
nn = Model(inputs=ip, outputs=x)
```

Below is the summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         (None, 500, 500, 500, 1)  0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)            (None, 500, 500, 500, 100 2800      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 500, 500, 500, 500 50500     
=================================================================
Total params: 53,300
Trainable params: 53,300
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

when I run the model I got the memory error as I have 64 GB RAM and quadroP5000 nvidia GPU.

Another way to make it working was to split the input to `100s` of `5x500x500` chunks thus making the network input of size `5x500x500` . Now I have `10000x100=1000000` samples of size `5x500x500`. Below is the modified network:

```
ip = Input(shape=(5,500,500,1))  
x = Conv3D(100,3,activation="relu",padding='same')(ip)
x = Dense(500,activation="softmax")(x)
nn = Model(inputs=ip, outputs=x)
```

below is the summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         (None, 5, 500, 500, 1)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)            (None, 5, 500, 500, 100)  2800      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 5, 500, 500, 500)  50500     
=================================================================
Total params: 53,300
Trainable params: 53,300
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Clearly the total number of parameters are same, but now I am able to train the network as I am able to load the data in RAM .But the network is not able to learn as it can't see all the information at once it can see only `5` of those. **The information is distributed over whole array of size `500x500x500`, so network can't figure out anything looking at only one chunk of size `5x500x500`.**
Please suggest me how to get over this. I want my network to use all the information for prediction not only one chunk.

Comment: Input is 3D and labels are 4D, what it represents?

Comment: @VivekMehta yes input is 3D and label is 4D. sorry to say that I can not disclose more about data, but there are are some statistics relation in the 3D data which can help predict 4D data and this relation is distributed all over 3D data and is very large to handle.   so looking for some way to utilize all the statistics relations even though I load one chunk in the memory at a time.

Comment: If you really need such hardcore image resolution, what about splitting the task in two phases: You made chunks of 3d data: 125 x batch*100*100*100*1/image for smaller spatial abstractions and meaning the loss. Then using batch*100*100*100*1/image i.e. using less resolution for larger spatials, then combining the 2 results? Combining so e.g. you made lower resolution part, extracting large general spatial features. After it you can feed these features merging them with at for Dense layer at  working with chunks. You can handle the two phases separately, summing/meaning the results.

Comment: But in most cases we can get better performance with reduced images resolution as we don't pick up noices, if we really don't need special small sized features as well.

Comment: @Geeocode : This is not an image, this is a  kind of some sensor data which shares spatial relationship. The question here is that if I split the feature in 2 part , will the network will able to learn the statistical relationship which distributed all over the input feature spatially.

Comment: I can not reduce the resolution as the data is very sensitive to small change

Comment: Doesn't matter that it is image or any spatially dependant data. You said that this is "very sensitive" meaning that the a model can learn on smaller chunks. But if your data is spatially extent to larger size as well as you have 500*500*500 datapoint, it means that it can be - we don't know from the info, that you really need -, but not always have meaningful spatial data. However if you still have you can made a separate smaller resolution task in parallel.

Comment: Do you use some pooling layer, to reduce the dimensionality?

Comment: @Geeocode: "very sensitive" means if I change the the feature little bit the corresponding label will be impacted more.
I tried some methods to reduce the dimension like PCA and also down sampled the data to smaller dimension but got bad results, As I am aware of the physics of the system I know that all the data points are important to predict the result.
I can use the pooling layer to reduce the dimension but I will have to up-sample it again to get back the required dimension. Here I am using very few layers even getting memory error.

Comment: What I'm saying that you have no choice I think. You get bigger GPU resource or you combine the lower and higher spatial infos with the method I proposed, though it is not comfortable, but in some cases can produce more generative power.

Comment: Ok ok I see thanks, but I was looking for something where network can try to find the relation across fixed batches.

Comment: How about using an encoder to reduce the size without loss of features. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder

Comment: @Reactgular: Sure, I will try that out, I have tried PCA which did not give a good result  but I have not tried Autoencoder as dimensional reduction. Any other suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: @All:  I was trying to treat each chunk as a sequence and use ConvLSTM at the input so that it may remember something from previous chunk and try to utilize that information. Will that give any upper hand ?

Answer (score 1):

You could resize your inputs before supplying them to the CNN. For example, I would go for 100x100x100 or even 50x50x50. Another option would be to add a Max/Mean/Average Pooling layer before the Convolution layer to have a sort of dimensionality reduction.

I had the same problem and I figured out that if I ran the whole process utilising only CPU it was working (but it was taking ages). I am not sure if this adds any value to your concerns.